# サイズの異なる行列の集合をパディングしてサイズを揃えたい

Tags: python, chainer

以下のように、サイズの異なる行列の集合Aが与えられた時、

```
A = 
[[[1, 2, 3],
  [1, 2, 3],
  [1, 2, 3]],
 [[1, 2],
  [1, 2],
  [1, 2],
  [1, 2]],
 [[1, 2, 3, 4],
  [1, 2, 3, 4]]]
```

以下のように、0でパディングして全体を連結させて、1つの行列にしたいです。

```
B =
[[1, 2, 3, 0],
 [1, 2, 3, 0],
 [1, 2, 3, 0],
 [1, 2, 0, 0],
 [1, 2, 0, 0],
 [1, 2, 0, 0],
 [1, 2, 0, 0],
 [1, 2, 3, 4],
 [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

Chainerで上のような入力と出力を実現するためには、
どのようなコードを書けば良いでしょうか？
AとBはnumpy array型です。

Comment: `A` も `B` も単なるリストですか？　それとも NumPy array ですか？

Comment: 表記が足りなかったです。すみません。NumPy arrayで大丈夫です。

Comment: NumPy array の場合、`A` の要素が長さの違うリストなので、型が気になります。`A.dtype` は何になりますか？

Comment: 今確認したら、A.dtypeはobjectになっていました。

Answer (score 1):

一旦、リストに変換します。

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([
 [[1, 2, 3],
  [1, 2, 3],
  [1, 2, 3]],
 [[1, 2],
  [1, 2],
  [1, 2],
  [1, 2]],
 [[1, 2, 3, 4],
  [1, 2, 3, 4]]])

## Flatten
X = sum(A.tolist(), [])
## Max size
l = max(map(len, X))
## Padding
B = np.array(map(lambda x: x + [0]*(l-len(x)), X))

B
=>
array([[1, 2, 3, 0],
       [1, 2, 3, 0],
       [1, 2, 3, 0],
       [1, 2, 0, 0],
       [1, 2, 0, 0],
       [1, 2, 0, 0],
       [1, 2, 0, 0],
       [1, 2, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 3, 4]])
```

Comment: 助かりました。ありがとうございます！上のコードを参考にして、うまくパディングできました。